# I am trying to convert an SQL query into a LINQ query

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I am trying to convert this exact SQL query which gets distinct flight paths between A and B into a LINQ query:

```
SELECT F1.DepartingFromId, F1.ArrivingAtId 
  FROM dbo.Flights AS F1 
 WHERE F1.DepartingFromId = 1 
 GROUP BY F1.ArrivingAtId, F1.DepartingFromId
```

If I use a `foreach (airport in airports)` over the above SQL, it'll get me a list of distinct paths, as in, paths only one of each A to B.

So far I have:

```
var dc = from flight in _DbContext.Flights
    where flight.DepartingFromId == airport.Id
    group flight by flight.ArrivingAtId
    into flightGroup
    select flightGroup;

foreach (var flightGroup in dc)
{
    foreach (var flight in flightGroup)
    {
        distinctFlights.Add(new DistinctConnection(flight.DepartingFromId, flight.ArrivingAtId));
    }
}
```

However, this is returning all the flights in the database. Which is like 200,000 rows. There should be about 70ish distinct connections.

Any help would be much appreciated, as I am new to LINQ/Lambda.

Comment: Have you checked the `DepartingFromId` and `airport.Id` values? PS: it's not obvious why you need `GROUP BY` here

Comment: It doesn't really make sense to have a `GROUP BY` clause in that SQL because there's no aggregate function.  It seems more logical to use the `DISTINCT` keyword and that's exactly what you should do in LINQ too.

Comment: Yeah, I am pretty sure there is nothing wrong with that part, I think the group in LINQ isn't the same as the group by in SQL.

Comment: While there's nothing "wrong" with `GROUP BY`, it is not a useful application because the purpose of `GROUP BY` is to facilitate aggregate queries. `DISTINCT` is the correct keyword when querying for distinct records.

Comment: Sorry, I don't disagree, and thank you very much for your comment. I just mean that the SQL isn't really my problem, it's getting the same result from LINQ which is the problem. My selected answer below worked.

Also thanks for letting me know about the Distinct keyword, I'll use that in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that this would be a clearer way to go - it avoids the unnecessary grouping:

```
distinctFlights.AddRange(
(
    from flight in _DbContext.Flights
    where flight.DepartingFromId == airport.Id
    select flight.ArrivingAtId
)
    .Distinct()
    .ToArray()
    .Select(x => new DistinctConnection(airport.Id, x)));
```

This should generate an efficient query in the database too.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why this would return all flights, because you are filtering on the `where` condition `flight.DepartingFromId == airport.Id`.

To get the distinct ones, select the

- group key value (`g.Key`) as `ArrivingAtId`
- the `DepartingFromId` you filtered on in the `where` clause (i.e. `airport.Id`)

Like this:

```
// Query for distinct connections from `airport.Id`.
var results = 
    from flight in _DbContext.Flights
    where flight.DepartingFromId == airport.Id
    group flight by flight.ArrivingAtId into g
    select new DistinctConnection(airport.Id, g.Key);

// Add them to the list.
distinctFlights.AddRange(results);
```

Comment: That worked, although I had to change to http://pastie.org/10195818
Thanks so much for your help.